# How to Apply Filter Couchbase Server Using c#

Tags: c#, .net, couchdb

This is my json Data

```
{
"_id":"biking",
"_rev":"AE19EBC7654",
"type":"user",
"body":"My biggest hobby is mountainbiking. The other day...",
"date":"2009/01/30 18:04:11"
}
{
"_id":"biking",
"_rev":"AE19EBC7654",
"type":"testuser",
"body":"My biggest hobby is mountainbiking. The other day...",
"date":"2009/01/30 18:04:11"
}
```

Here is what is tried so far

```
var pull = _db.CreatePullReplication(syncGatewayUri);
var push = _db.CreatePushReplication(syncGatewayUri);

 _db.SetFilter("byUser", (revision, filterParams) =>
{
var typeParam = filterParams["type"].ToString();

return (typeParam != null) && typeParam.Equals("USer");
});

pull.Filter ="byUser";
```

i want to get result that contain only type user. But i not able to apply filter.

Comment: Is it a typo or you're trying to compare `user` with `USer` which has not the same casing?

Comment: i tried that user but not getting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if you want to create a filter for Users only, you don't need a param. What you want to do is return true if the document's type is "user".

Here's an example :

```
var pull = _db.CreatePullReplication(syncGatewayUri);
var push = _db.CreatePushReplication(syncGatewayUri);

 _db.SetFilter("byUser", (revision, filterParams) =>
{
  //We get the type property
  var docType = (string)revision.GetProperty("type");
  //We make sure it's a user
  return !String.IsNullOrEmpty(docType) && docType.toLowerCase() == "user";
});

pull.Filter ="byUser";
```

If you want to be more dynamic, you can create a filter byType and specify the "user" type parameter.

Example :

```
var pull = _db.CreatePullReplication(syncGatewayUri);
var push = _db.CreatePushReplication(syncGatewayUri);

 _db.SetFilter("byType", (revision, filterParams) =>
{
var typeParam = filterParams["type"].ToString();
var docType = (string)revision.GetProperty("type");
return (typeParam != null) && !String.isNullOrEmpty(docType) && typeParam.toLowerCase() == docType.toLowerCase();
})

pull.Filter ="byType";
pull.FilterParams = new Dictionary<string, object> { {"type", "user"} };
```

For more details, see [CouchBase](https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/mobile/current/guides/couchbase-lite/native-api/replication/index.html) documentation.

Comment: I tried that one also but not getting only type user

Comment: Can you add some log to see what are the values passed to your functions? For eg, is the docType value correct, are the parameters passed correctly?